# Result of function can't be passed as reference

Tags: c++, reference

After years of AS3, I'm trying to relearn C++. References are still giving me fits.

Consider the following functions:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <list>

void f(std::list<int>& v) {
  for (std::list<int>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
    printf("Hello %d\n", *i);
}

std::list<int> get(void) {
  std::list<int> list;
  list.push_back(0);
  return list;
}
```

Now, doing the following:

```
std::list<int> l = get();
f(l);
```

is fine, but `f(get())` will produce the following error:

> "no matching function for call to 'f'", "candidate function not viable: no known conversion from `'std::list<int>' to 'std::list<int>&' for 1st argument"

Why is that? Is it because the result of a function is invisibly `const`?

Comment: For once I prefer gcc's error message to clang's:
`error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >&' from a temporary of type 'std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do this:

```
f(get());
```

you pass a temporary `std::list<int>` to `f()`. A temporary cannot bind to a non-const reference. So you can fix this by passing a `const` reference, since you do not want to modify the argument.

```
void f(const std::list<int>& v) 
{ //   ^^^^^
  for (std::list<int>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
  { //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    printf("Hello %d\n", *i);
  }
}
```

Note that this requires that you use a `const_iterator`, since `std::list::begin() const` and the corresponding `end()` method return `const_iterator`s. In C++11 you can simplify this to

```
for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
  ...
```

or even

```
for (const auto& i : v)
  std::cout << i << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a temporary `std::list` variable from the `get()` method. This doesn't work because your argument is not `const` to function `f`.

Answer (score -1):

That's because your argument is T&. It it was T cont&, it worked fine.

Some old compilers made your version work as extension -- the rule is somewhat arbitrary, and is there to avoid surprise. T& arg means OUT (or INOUT) type, and if modifications end up in a temporary, it is a surprise.